# curl_exec returns blank with no errors

Tags: php, curl

I make a curl call which seems to go fine.

`[http_code] => 200`, and `curl_errno` is 0.

Yet despite the fact there should be an output (`[download_content_length] => 102`), the curl_exec call doesn't return anything.

```
define('_WSURL', 'https://mobistar.msgsend.com/mmp/cp3'); // Feel free to try it yourself

$stderr = fopen("err.log", 'w+');
if ($stderr !== false) {
  print "Opened the log file without errors";
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, _WSURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $stderr);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR.'c00kie.txt'); 

$data = curl_exec($ch);

fclose($stderr);

print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));

print_r($data);

if ($data === false)
{ // Process curl error codes here
    echo('ERROR');
    echo(curl_errno($ch));
} else {
    echo(sprintf('DATA: [%s]', $data));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

How comes?

Comment: what url are you trying to access?

Comment: a webservice's reponse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returns a response for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response code="499" description="The XML Content is Invalid"/>
```

I suspect you're seeing a blank page in your browser. If it's so, take a look at the page source in the browser, the XML should be there.

Comment: No, I see a blank result in the php calls output ($data). When I browse to the page I get the xml as you do. Yet, I'm starting to think the webservice bugs in some way. So if anybody can copy, run my code and tells me what's wrong it would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Arg, I'm so stupid sometimes...

The response is a XML and **I tried to output it directly in the HTML**, but of course it's just considered a set of invalid tags **thus display as blank**.

I should have taken a closer look to the source code XD